# "The problem is solved with a/the standard method of k-decomposition"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I have ceased to understand which article must be used there. On the one hand (suppose that the mentioned method exists and has no namesakes) it is *the* method. But on the other hand, there are many standard methods and this is *one* of them.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any further context, "A" implies that there are several standard methods of k-decomposition, and you are using one of them but not, at this point, specifying which; "the" implies that there is only one standard method of k-decomposition.

If you have previously identified the method being used, then "the" picks it out without implying that it is the only one.

Comment: so, in neither case the sentence means that I use **the** (only existing)  method of k-decomposition, which is **one of**  standard methods?

Comment: It could mean that with enough context, @Serguei; but I would not understand that to be the meaning otherwise.